# Ionic app - android problem with access to photo gallery

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, android-camera, capacitor

I'm creating some ionic capacitor app and I have problem with new Android phones. I have a screen with some button that allows user to set his profile picture. When user clicks button for the first time the app asks for permissions "Allow {APP_NAME} to access photos, videos, music and audio on this device?" and when user allow this permissions then it is still impossible to open gallery to choose photos.

I can see this error message in console:

`I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/default-src_app_shared_shared_module_ts.js - Line 2195 - Msg: Error: Missing the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

I'm sure I have this permission in AndroidManifest.xml because I checked it a few times and it is there. I can't find anything that may help me to fix it.

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="io.the.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!-- capacitor-background-geolocation licence -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.license" android:value="" />
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="io.the.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
</manifest>
```

My capacitor doctor:

```
   Capacitor Doctor   

Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 4.7.0
  @capacitor/core: 4.7.0
  @capacitor/android: 4.7.0
  @capacitor/ios: 4.7.0

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 4.6.1
  @capacitor/core: 4.6.1
  @capacitor/android: 4.6.1
  @capacitor/ios: 4.6.1

[success] iOS looking great! 
[success] Android looking great!
```

My camera plugin version:

`"@capacitor/camera": "^4.1.4",`

My function for adding photo looks like this:

```
handleAddPhoto = async () => {
    await Camera.checkPermissions().then((permissions) => {
        if (permissions.photos !== 'granted') {
            Camera.requestPermissions();
        }
    });
    const photo = await Camera.getPhoto({
        quality: 50,
        resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
        source: CameraSource.Photos,
    });
    this.avatarSrc = this.sanitizeSrc(photo.base64String);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.handleSavePhoto('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + photo.base64String);
};
```

Comment: Please post your androidManifest.xml. It is possible that the entry is in the wrong section or otherwise misconfigured.

Comment: @E.Maggini I completely forgot to add it before. It is already here

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with async handling. I'm mildly surprised this compiled properly for you.

It is possible that appending a `.then` to your checkPermissions call effectively negates the `await`.

If so, your application is continuing along to the getPhoto call before requesting permissions. Perhaps try this:

```
async function getCameraPermission(): Promise<boolean> {
  if (hasCameraPermission(await Camera.checkPermissions())) {
    return true;
  }

  const result = hasCameraPermission(await Camera.requestPermissions({ permissions: ['camera'] }));

  // We need to wait for a moment to let the UI catch up on iOS so that the user doesn't have to request the camera more than once. This
  // will only occur where camera permissions have not been requested or revoked. Once permissions have been granted, this code will be
  // unreachable.
  await sleep(500);

  return result;
}

function hasCameraPermission({ camera }: PermissionStatus): boolean {
  switch (camera) {
    case 'granted':
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

async function handleAddPhoto(): Promise<string> {
  if (await getCameraPermission()) {
    const { dataUrl } = await Camera.getPhoto({
        quality: 50,
        resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
        source: CameraSource.Photos,
    });

    if (dataUrl) {
      return dataUrl;
    }
  }

  throw new Error('Permission to access the camera was denied or the camera returned nothing.');
}
```

Comment: It didn't change anything. Still the same error in console

Comment: And you ran `cap sync` after making the change?

Comment: Yes, I did new build, cap sync etc.

Comment: I debugged your solution and the problem is that most of code is not even executed because it fails on requesting permissions because it can't see android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Well, I am truly stumped then. The only other thing to suggest is perhaps matching what is  showing in the documentation regarding the permissions. In the example, there is no reference to  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> . Seems counter-intuitive but worth trying. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/camera